# Rolling Row Subtraction

Tags: r, row, subtraction

I am looking to perform a row subtraction, where I have a group of individuals and I want to subtract the more recent row from the row above it (like a rolling row subtraction). Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

The data would look something like this:

```
    Name Day variable.1
1   Bob   1       43.4
2   Bob   2       32.0
3   Bob   3       18.1
4   Bob   4       41.2
5   Bob   5       85.2
6  Jeff   1       17.4
7  Jeff   2       55.6
8  Jeff   3       58.7
9  Jeff   4       40.6
10 Jeff   5       77.3
11 Carl   1       52.9
12 Carl   2       71.7
13 Carl   3       84.3
14 Carl   4       54.8
15 Carl   5       69.7
```

For example, for Bob, I would like it to come out as:

```
    Name Day variable.1
1   Bob   1       NA
2   Bob   2       -11.4
3   Bob   3       -13.9
4   Bob   4       23.1
5   Bob   5       44
```

And then it would go to the next name and perform the same task.

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[,variable.1:=c(NA,diff(variable.1)) , Name]
```

Or using `shift` from the devel version of `data.table` (as suggested by @Jan Gorecki).  Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
setDT(df1)[, variable.1 := variable.1- shift(variable.1), Name]
```

Comment: and what about `shift`? already stable feature

Answer (score 3):

You can use the base `ave()` function. For example, if your data is in a data.frame named `dd`,

```
dd$newcol <-ave(dd$variable.1, dd$Name, FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(diff = variable.1-lag(variable.1))
Source: local data frame [15 x 4]
Groups: Name

   Name Day variable.1  diff
1   Bob   1       43.4    NA
2   Bob   2       32.0 -11.4
3   Bob   3       18.1 -13.9
4   Bob   4       41.2  23.1
5   Bob   5       85.2  44.0
6  Jeff   1       17.4    NA
7  Jeff   2       55.6  38.2
8  Jeff   3       58.7   3.1
9  Jeff   4       40.6 -18.1
10 Jeff   5       77.3  36.7
11 Carl   1       52.9    NA
12 Carl   2       71.7  18.8
13 Carl   3       84.3  12.6
14 Carl   4       54.8 -29.5
15 Carl   5       69.7  14.9
```

Comment: DatamineR, that is great! It worked well. The only other problem I have is some individuals have different numbers of data. For example, Bob might have 5 rows but Jeff only 3. Is there a quick work around for that? Thank you,

Comment: It should not be a problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have. It gives me some error saying, "Error: wrong result size (46), expected 23 or 1"

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example?